# Infinite loop warning when running this for n > 3?

Tags: performance, infinite-loop

I am trying to get an average for how long the function battle2 takes to run. This is part of a little personal project of mine to test how different ways of writing code affect time efficiency (I'm a beginner). This seems to works fine for n <= 3 but totally crashes for anything higher than that (ideally I'd have n = 100) and I can't figure out why except maybe that battle2 already contains a for loop and putting one on top of it slows it down too much? Thank you for any insight!

Second question: It doesn't happen with this code in particular but sometimes when I use performance.now() on smaller snippets of code, it logs as taking 0 milliseconds...? Is this because it happened so fast, the computer couldn't record a time or this something else?

```
//Second version of my rock, paper, scissors function
function battle2(p1, p2){
  var shoot = ["rock", "scissors", "paper"];
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    if (p1 === shoot[i] && p2 === shoot[(i + 2) % 3]){
      return "p2";
    }
    else if (p1 === shoot[i] && p2 === shoot[(i + 1) % 3]){
      return "p1";
    }
    if (p1 === p2 ){
      return "p0";
    }
  }
}

//Create empty array and sum variables to collect values each pass of the 
  loop
n = 4    
var array2 = [];
var sum2 = 0;

//Repeat the code below this line n times
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){

  //Randomly generate p1 and p2 choice each time through the loop
  var choicesB = ["rock", "scissors", "paper"];
  var randomB = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  var random2B = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
  p1 = choicesB[randomB];
  p2 = choicesB[random2B];

  //Check performance on battle2 each time through the loop
  var start2B = performance.now();
  battle2(p1,p2);
  var duration2B = performance.now() - start2B;

  //Sometimes performance.now() logs as 0 (why?), so I ignore those instances 
    here
  if (duration2B !== 0){
    array2.push(duration2B);
    sum2 += duration2B;
  }
}
var average2 = sum2/array2.length;
console.log(average2)
```

Comment: Nested `for` loops will compound iterations exponentially, so if the outer loop runs 100 times and the inner loop runs 100 times, it will total 10,000 iterations (100*100). For small values of `n` it's not a big deal but as `n` gets larger it can get out of control quickly.

If you're getting some sort of infinite loop when n = 4 then something else is wrong. Check that you're not stepping on any global values in your program. Try adding `"use strict"` as the first line in your `.js` file which should flag if there are any undeclared globals.

Comment: In practice `performance.now()` should never return `0` as far as I can tell; and `var now = performance.now(); performance.now() - now` should return results in the microsecond range (`0.005000000004656613` for example).